# Difference between FreeTDS and unixodbc?

Tags: freetds, unixodbc

I'm trying to work out how these two pieces of the jigsaw interact and fit together when connecting to an MS-SQL server on linux.

As I understand it, FreeTDS is protocol (i.e. a set of rules) for talking to MS-SQL and it is the thing that actually does the talking. Unixodbc is a driver that implements the ODBC API, i.e. implements a set of functions I guess.

Why are both things necessary? Can anyone elaborate on my sketchy understanding of what these two things actually do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`unixODBC` is a 'DriverManager' for ODBC. You can use `unixODBC` when on a Linux or *nix system to connect to any ODBC-capable database. Doing so means that you can write one lot of database queries which you should be able to use between different databases. If you were not on Unix, you would use a different Driver Manager, for example the built-in MS Office one.

To make all the components clear: if you're using a language, let's say Python, to connect to SQL Server, your connection might pass from Python's pyodbc (translates python objects to and from unixODBC), to unixODBC (manages drivers, such as FreeTDS), to FreeTDS (translates unixODBC objects to and from the TDS protocol, which Microsoft embraces) to SQL Server.

The `unixODBC` website http://www.unixodbc.org/ says:

> An ODBC application makes ODBC calls to the DriverManager. The DriverManager carries out a number of tasks for the application such as:
>
> - ensuring the proper driver is loaded/unloaded
> - validation tasks
> - 3.5 to 3.0 to 2.0 call and data mapping
>
> Most calls to the DriverManager get passed onto the loaded Driver to be further processed but that is of little concern to the application.
>
> Some advantages to using an ODBC DriverManager include:
>
> - portable data access code
> - runtime binding to a Data Source
> - ability to easily change the Data Source

Briefly, it is the Driver Manager which reads your DSN, looks at the configured data sources, and decides where and how to connect.

Depending on which database you use, you will need a different driver. This piece of code 'translates' your requests made using ODBC to the right protocol for the relevant database management system. This is the component that would need to be different for different data sources. In your case, TDS is the protocol used by MS SQL Server. FreeTDS is a free software implementation of this protocol.

See also Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity (emphasis kept):

> ODBC accomplishes DBMS independence by using an **ODBC driver** as a translation layer between the application and the DBMS. The application uses ODBC functions through an **ODBC driver manager** with which it is linked, and the driver passes the query to the DBMS. An ODBC driver can be thought of as analogous to a printer driver or other driver, providing a standard set of functions for the application to use, and implementing DBMS-specific functionality. An application that can use ODBC is referred to as "ODBC-compliant". Any ODBC-compliant application can access any DBMS for which a driver is installed. Drivers exist for all major DBMSs, many other data sources like address book systems and Microsoft Excel, and even for text or CSV files.

Comment: Great answer. To simplify in a real-world example, if you're using a language, let's say Python, to connect to SQL Server, your connection might pass from Python's pyodbc (translates python objects to and from unixODBC), to unixODBC (managers drivers, such as FreeTDS), to FreeTDS (translates unixODBC objects to and from the TDS protocol, that Microsoft embraces) to SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment @FlipperPA, do you mind if I edit it into the answer since I think it make things very clear?

Comment: Go for it! Whatever helps others the most, and it's a confusing stack. :)

Answer (score 1):

FreeTDS is the implementation of the TDS protocol, it handles everything and is fully capable of operating without unixODBC.

ODBC is a wrapper around FreeTDS and provides a common API that is better documented than FreeTDS' internal API.

As FreeTDS.org/faq.html indicates:
FreeTDS offers three client libraries and one internal one (libtds). We generally encourage people to use one of the client libraries, and discourage writing to libtds, because the latter is evolving, more subject to change, less well documented, and harder to use.

Both pieces aren't necessary, it's just that some people prefer to use wrappers rather than learn a new API to do something similar to what they already know in a different API. As FreeTDS' FAQ indicates, they support other open APIs other than ODBC and their internal library is fully capable of handling the connection all on its own.